# Can I use jQuery find() for more than one element type at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following function to change the padding in a column on my forms:

```
function padTitles() {
    $('#option-grid #dataTable tr, #topic-grid #dataTable tr')
        .each(function () {
            var tds = $(this).find('input'),
        text = tds.filter('[id^="input_TempRowKey_"]').val(),
        tdToPad = tds.filter('[id^="input_Title_"]'),
        pad;
            if (/\.0$/.test(text)) {
                pad = 10;
                level = 1;
            } else {
                pad = 35;
                level = 2;
            }
            tdToPad.css('margin-left', pad);
            a = tdToPad.closest('tr');
            if (tdToPad.closest('tr').get().className) {
                tdToPad.closest('tr').get().className = tdToPad.closest('tr').get().className.replace(/\blevel\-.*?\b/g, 'level-' + level);
            } else {
                tdToPad.closest('tr').addClass('level-' + level)
            }
        });
}
```

It works well for this form HTML:

```
<td id="title_1" class=" ">
   <input type="text" value="Tests" name="item.Title" id="input_Title_1" >
</td>
```

Now I would also like it to work for the following HTML:

```
<td id="title_1" class=" ">    
  <textarea name="item.Title" id="input_Title_1">Tests</textarea>
</td>
```

Is there a way I can change this function so it works for either an `input` or `textarea`?  I assume the way to do this is to change `var tds = $(this).find('input'),` however I am not sure how to change it or even if it's possible to change to "find" either a textarea or an input.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use a comma to union multiple queries:

```
var tds = $(this).find('input, textarea');
```

You can also use `:input` as a selector, but it's not as efficient and may also include some things you'd rather not include.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.children()` to select the `td`s child whatever it is

```
var tds = $(this).children();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a `textarea` with the same `id` as another element. Its incorrect. `id` values are unique for a single html element within the document.

I would suggest to you `class` instead.

```
<input type="text" value="Tests" class="myclass" name="item.Title" id="input_Title_1" >

<textarea name="item.Title" class="myclass" id="input_Title_2">Tests</textarea>

var tds = $(this).find('.myclass')
```

Comment: One form uses a textarea another uses an input. Sorry I should have mentioned it's two different forms.

Comment: If both forms are in same page, its still invalid .

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )
```

selector1: Any valid selector.
selector2: Another valid selector.
selectorN: As many more valid selectors as you like.
The order of the DOM elements in the returned `jQuery` object may not be identical, as they will be in document order.
**Example**: Finds the elements that match any of these three selectors.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>multiple demo</title>
  <style>
  div, span, p {
    width: 126px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>div</div>
<p class="myClass">p class="myClass"</p>
<p class="notMyClass">p class="notMyClass"</p>
<span>span</span>
 
<script>
$( "div, span, p.myClass" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[Read More](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)